# How to uninstall and re-install a stable version?

Tags: qgis, installation, osx

I just posted about a DEM problem after installing the latest nightly build...now I am completely screwed.  I uninstalled the latest nightly build and associated files, hoping to resort back to the stable version, which had been working great...until my great idea of checking out the developer version.

I just want to get the stable version up and running again.  I thought I could just uninstall everything, then reinstall, then bingo...but it's not happening.  Maybe I am missing some files somewhere that I never deleted?  Any help would be most appreciated.  Just so you know, I am a computer idiot...only very basic skills when it comes to technical troubleshooting.

Oh, and I'm running Mac OS X 10.8 Mt. Lion on a 2007 intel based macbook pro.

Comment: I think at least one of my problems is that when I started un-installing everything, I also trashed my Python fold in "Library" directory.  I need to re-install these, but not sure where to get them.

Comment: The nightly build for Mac uses the same underlying frameworks for support (from Kyngchaos.com) as the stable version (2.0.1). To 'uninstall' the nightly, just move the app to the Trash and empty it. You can have both the nightly and the stable version installed and running at the same time. However, don't do work on the same project in both; and, since they both use the same settings file, it may become corrupt when using the development version (rare). So, be careful if running both. Your situation of deleting your system Python's site-packages setup is a bit dire, but can be reconstructed.

Answer (score 3):

One way to fix a whole slew of dependency problems is to just install everything via homebrew (http://brew.sh).  Brew has a working qgis stable version available and it can also install a version of python to use for all its dependencies.  Deleting the system python is bad, but you can mostly fix that by just installing the python 2.7 dmg from python.org.  That may get your system back in shape enough to do the regular stable version, but I still highly recommend using brew for all this stuff as it just makes it much easier.

I actually recently came up with gist for a geog class detailing installing qgis as well as a bunch of other geog software using brew here: https://gist.github.com/timofei7/8390871  in particular there are a few formula taps that help get all the right dependencies -- I believe the qgis-20 formula via homebrew depends on python having numpy/scipy so this gist has those details.

Answer (score 0):

I got mine from my original system disk (see http://johnsankey.ca/python.html for what I needed to do). Good luck - in my experience you're going to need it.